# How can I access Role the security context token in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I access Role the security context token in symfony 2?

following code in Controller file in welcomeAcation

```
$usernames  = $session->get('usernames');
$password = $session->get('password');
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($usernames, $password, 'secured_area', array('ROLE_USER','CMS_CONTROL_VIEW','CMS_CONTROL_EDIT','CMS_CONTROL_LIKE'));
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

i have costume role applied in user  and how to get twig file access in role ?

i have following code right in twig file
**Welcome {{ app.security.getToken() }} !**
AND print to

```
UsernamePasswordToken(user="testuser", authenticated=true, roles="CMS_CONTROL_VIEW, CMS_CONTROL_EDIT, CMS_CONTROL_ADD") !
```

but not run bellow

```
{% if is_granted('CMS_CONTROL_EDIT') %}
echo "test";
{% endif %}
```

how to  role check in twig file ?

Comment: Do you by any chance have more than 1 firewalls (not including `dev` and `profiler`)??

Comment: only one firewalls
i have add security.yml in above my question 
pl check is ok ?

Comment: What is the output of {{ dump(app.user.roles) }} in your twig template?

Comment: {{ dump(app.user.roles) }}   to out put - > Impossible to access an attribute ("roles") on a NULL variable ("") in BackendAdminBundle:Secured:welcome.html.twig at line 14